# Remove credentials created with Web Authentication API

Tags: windows-security, webauthn, windows-hello

Does anyone know where the security credentials from Windows Hello are located and how to delete them?

I am implementing authentication with Web Authentication API and while working on the code I created hundreds of credentials, which I would like to delete somehow.

```
navigator.credential.get({ ... })
```

Just calling `get()` takes a minute or two to load all of them and show this dialog:

[image: windows security credentials]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Citing from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1527685/how-to-remove-webauthn-credentials-from-onboard-tpm-on-win10-device):

> The Microsoft command line tool certutil can be used to view and
> delete these WebAuthN keys.
>
> Disclaimer: it's very easy to delete the wrong key, so make sure that
> you are happy to accept the risk that you might delete the wrong key;
> there is no undo.
>
> To view your WebAuthN keys, from a command prompt, run:
>
> certutil -csp NGC -key
>
> WebAuthN keys have names that look like
> //FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR//_
>
> You need to identify the key that you want to delete, and then to
> delete a WebAuthN key, from an administrator command prompt, run:
>
> certutil -csp NGC -delkey

Spontaneous hint, use Chrome with the dev tools and an emulated platform authenticator: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/